# MS Edge can't detect delegated events for <use> SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, svg, microsoft-edge

I think I've found a troubling bug with MS Edge that impacts on dynamically created SVG `<use>` elements. Edge seems to be able to detect directly bound events, i.e. `$('.use').on('click', ...)`, however delegated events `$('body').on('click', 'use', ...)` are ignored.

It is most easily illustrated with a JS Fiddle (tested in Chrome, where both bindings in work and in Edge where the delegated binding doesn't work):
https://jsfiddle.net/Lr0arahb/

Does anyone have any insight on this issue, and knows of a possible workaround? Foremost, I'm looking for a solution where we can still use the `<use>` elements as it's imperative for our SPA.

Comment: You do realize that IE11 and Microsoft Edge are two completely separate browsers, right?

Comment: Haha, I did not, that's quite alarming, the question has been edited, this is for Edge. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 7):

I too have found this with Edge 13. It's definetly a hack rather than a solid solution but to work around it I put the SVG in a container and used a transparent pseudo-element to cover the SVG. This way the pseudo-element gets the click rather than the SVG.

Example SVG icon used in a button:

```
<button class="close" type="button">
  <svg role="img" class="icon icon--close">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#close" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

CSS Fix:

```
.close {
  /* Make it so the pseudo-element is relative to this parent element */
  position: relative;
}

.close:after {
  /* Cover the button with a pseudo-element so the SVG can't be clicked */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Doesn't this deserve to be marked as the answer? I ran into the same problem and this answer solved it.

Comment: Although it's a nice hack, this isn't a sufficient solution for an svg with multiple elements, so it doesn't really solve the question.

Comment: We have also solved this by transferring the click event off of the <svg> and onto the containing element, coupled with a pointer-events:none; on the <svg> element. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pointer-events: none` can solve this. Instead of applying it to the `<svg>` tag and attaching handlers to a container element as is mentioned in a comment, if you add `pointer-events: none` to the `<use>` itself, this prevents it from stopping event propagation, and the outer `<svg>` can still be receptive to mouse events.